# Django, how to call python from JS?

Tags: javascript, python, django, function

i work on a framework called Chatterbot 0.6. It's coded in Python.

The project is based on a website and a bot. The bot is implemented on the website and the user can speak with him through a chatbox.

Until here, i did the chat bot in python and the web site. The mission is to implement the bot on the website thanks to Django. I always managed to implements the website but now, i have to make the bot works.

The chatbox is coded in JS and the bot in Python. My mate who coded the site made a JS Function that prompt in the chatbox the bot's answer.

My question is : How to implement the Python in my JS function ?

```
var $msg_holder = undefined;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $msg_holder = $("#message_holder");
});

/**Function that appends a String (msg) to a DOM element ($dom)
*@param msg being the String to append (String object or literal string)
*@param $dom being a JQobject/JQselection of a DOM element to append the msg to
*/
function appendToDom(msg, $dom){
    $(msg).appendTo($dom);
}



/**Function that append a String (msg) to the Message Holder
*@param msg being the String to append (String object or string literal)
*/
function appendToMessageHolder(msg){
    appendToDom("<li>"+msg+"</li>", $("#message_holder"));
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////

/**Function that gets the amount of messages currently on the page
*@return the amount of messages currently on the page (unsigned integer)
*/
function processMsgCount(){
    var $ul = $("#message_holder");
    var $li = $ul.children("li");

    return Math.abs($li.length);//overkill to ensure that a positive number is returned
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////

/**Function that determines if it's the User's turn to give a sentence (in the scenario bot-->user user-->bot)
*@return TRUE if it's indeed the user's turn, FALSE otherwise
*/
function isUserTurn(){
    var ret = false;

    var MSGcount = processMsgCount();

    //if odd, then it's the User's turn
    if(MSGcount%2 != 0){
        ret = true
    }


    return ret;
}



/**Function that determines if it's the Bot's turn to give a sentence (in the scenario bot-->user user-->bot)
*@return TRUE if it's indeed the bot's turn, FALSE otherwise
*/
function isBotTurn(){
    return !isUserTurn();
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////

/**Function that displays the User's Input (wrapper function)
*@param msg being the user input itself (String object or literal string)
*/
function displayUserInput(msg){
    //condition is overkill, but meh 200% > 100%
    if(isUserTurn()){
        appendToMessageHolder(msg);
        scrollToLastMessage();//scroll down when new message
    }else{
//        console.log("user tried to input a sentence when it was the bot's turn :x");
        console.error("user tried to input a sentence when it was the bot's turn :x");
    }
}



/**Function that displays the Bot's Response to the User's Input (or display the initial sentence)
*@param msg being the bot's message/response (String object or literal string)
*/
function displayBotResponse(msg){
    //condition is overkill, but meh 200% > 100%
    if(isBotTurn()){
        appendToMessageHolder(msg);
        scrollToLastMessage();//scroll down when new message
    }else{
//        console.log("how the fuck did the bot try to give another message without user's input ?_?");
        console.error("how the fuck did the bot try to give another message without user's input ?_?");
    }

}
```

Sorry for the bad use of tags --'

Thanks a lot !

Comment: You cannot "implement Python in your JS function". In your case you should communicate with Python (Django server) with AJAX requests from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Python run at server side whereas your js function must be running on client side as you mentioned above.

Executing Python from js is not at all possible as per my information.More importantly this is bad practice for what you are trying to achieve.

How can we achieve ?

Ajax is good starting point for you I would suggest you to look into it.Shoot an Ajax request and make your bot or whatever piece of Python you want to run on some event.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Before i post this i saw here and there Ajax, i'll check to this side. But, for exemple, if i wan to initialize my bot before he answers questions, i have to load the script in first on my HTML page ? (with Ajax request to initialize the bot ? )